# Google Earth Engine dictionary error

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to run a Random Forest Model and was running into memory issues. I was able to work around this by exporting and importing but now I am getting the following error. I have broken the scripts up so this is the second script that include the large composite image I created that I want to classify. Any idea on the best way to convert my featurecollection into float?

> Dictionary (Error)
> Property 'Class' of feature '00000000000000000000_0': Invalid type.
> Expected type: Float.
> Actual type: String.
> Actual value: 1

My script is below and also found in the link (I believe I shared my assets) https://code.earthengine.google.com/7e8fbd7eeb7486fbe3fae2e2380f1e3a:

```
    //Step 2 Import Predictor Variable composite into this script to work around
//memory issues
//Map.addLayer(NSSentComp);
//Calculate mean and standard deviation within cluster segments

//Display NSSentComp to confirm it was exported/imported correctly
Map.addLayer(NSSentComp)
//SEGMENTATION - Set Sentinel-2 4 band mosaic for segmentation
//Set seeds for segmentation and apply softening
var seeds = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.seedGrid(36, 'hex');
var kernel = ee.Kernel.gaussian(3);
//Use RGBI and slope bands to create objects.
var segcomp = NSSentComp.select(['B2_median', 'B3_median', 'B4_median', 'B8_median', 'slope']).bandNames();
print(segcomp);
//Smooth the segmented image
var segcompsmoo = NSSentComp.convolve(kernel);

//Segment Sent/Slope Composite
var snic2 = ee.Algorithms.Image.Segmentation.SNIC({
  image: segcompsmoo,
  size:6,
  compactness: 0.2,  
  connectivity: 4,
  neighborhoodSize: 64,
  seeds: seeds
}).reproject({crs: 'EPSG: 26920',
scale: 5
});
var clusters2 = snic2.select('clusters')
Map.addLayer(snic2.randomVisualizer(), null, 'clusters2', false);
print(clusters2, "clusters2")
//Calculate stats per cluster for all predictor variables calculating mean and Stdev
var allStats = NSSentComp.reduceConnectedComponents({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean().combine({
 reducer2:ee.Reducer.stdDev(),
  sharedInputs:true
  }),
  labelBand: 'clusters2',
  maxSize: 512  
  })
print(allStats, "allstats")
var Clusterstats = allStats; 
print (Clusterstats, "Clusterstats");  //print to check bands were created as expected
//Map.addLayer(Clusterstats);

//Import training samples and train reduced image above

var trainVector = ee.FeatureCollection ('projects/ee-jrgallop/assets/RFTrainingDT');
var trainPoints = Clusterstats.sampleRegions({
  collection: trainVector,
  scale: 5,  //This is the scale we want the clusters to be processed at
  tileScale: 16, //want tilesize to be large enough to contain clusters, but too large will produce memory errors
  geometries: true,  //adding this enables you to export to asset
  });
  //print(trainPoints, "trainPoints")
  // Export to Asset requires the feature collection to have geometries, 
Export.table.toAsset({
  collection: trainPoints,
  description:'trainPoints',
  assetId: 'trainPoints',
});
  //Split training points into training and validation
  //var trainPoints = Table;
  var trainPoints = trainPoints.randomColumn();
  var split = 0.8;
  var training = trainPoints.filter(ee.Filter.lt('random', split));  //80% training
var validation = trainPoints.filter(ee.Filter.gte('random', split));  //20% validation
//print(trainPoints)
//Train the Classifier

var predictionVar = 

['B2_median_mean', 'B2_median_stdDev', 'B3_median_mean', 'B3_median_stdDev', 'B4_median_mean','B4_median_stdDev', 
'B8_median_mean','B8_median_stdDev','slope_mean', 'slope_stdDev','DEV150_mean', 'DEV150_stdDev', 'DEV500_mean', 
'DEV500_stdDev','DEV1000_mean', 'DEV1000_stdDev', 'WAM_mean', 'WAM_stdDev','REIP_mean', 'REIP_stdDev', 'NARI_mean', 
'NARI_stdDev','NDWI_mean', 'NDWI_stdDev', 'EVI_mean', 'EVI_stdDev', 'ndvi_mean', 'ndvi_stdDev', 'CHM_mean', 
'CHM_stdDev'];

var trainedRF = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest({numberOfTrees: 100}).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'Class',  //Name of the field with the class labels
  inputProperties:predictionVar
});
print (trainedRF.explain());
//Classify

var classifiedRF = Clusterstats.classify(trainedRF).float();

//Map.addLayer(classifiedRF)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it can be observed in the error message, your Feature Collection named **training** has a property with invalid type. You can fix this with following function before **trainedRF** variable.

```
var training = training.map(function (ele){
  
  var class_as_number = ee.Number.parse((ele.get('Class')));
  
  return ele.set('Class', class_as_number);
  
});
```

After that, your code run without any problem (dictionary is printed as expected); as it can be observed in following picture.

[image]

Complete code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/eb30a340d9d2cf1f9e4aaaf5aa37e811).

Comment: this works! Great! Thanks!

Comment: So, could you mark as accepted the answer? Thanks.